# Listview; No tooltip with RTL layout

Tags: windows, listview, delphi, tooltip

I have set my `TListView` to RTL (right to left) layout using code bellow. Now I realized The tooltip isn't shown. If I remove `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` (and thus control isn't RTL anymore) the problem solved and tooltip is shown.

I want tooltip to be shown while Listview is in RTL layout.

I think maybe one solution is to make the tooltip window (if it has a window) changed to RTL layout too, but I don't know how.

```pascal
procedure SetControlLayout(Control: TWinControl; RTL: Boolean);
const
  LVM_FIRST = $1000;
  LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31;   // ListView header messages
var
  Header: thandle;
  NewLong: NativeInt;
begin
  if Control is TListView then
  begin
    Header:= SendMessage(Control.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
    if RTL then
      NewLong:= GetWindowLong (Header, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
        //or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT
    else
      NewLong:= 0;

    SetWindowLongPtr(Header, GWL_EXSTYLE, NewLong);
  end;

  if RTL then
    NewLong:= GetWindowLong(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)  or
      WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or
      WS_EX_RTLREADING or
      WS_EX_LEFT
      //or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT
  else
    NewLong:= 0;

  SetWindowLongPtr(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, NewLong );

  Control.invalidate; 
end;
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you set the ListView's `BiDiMode` property to `bdRightToLeft` instead of using `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` manually?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, No problem using `BiDiMode` instead of `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`.

Comment: Why didn't you use `BiDiMode` in the first place? There are all kinds of things that the VCL accounts for internally when `BiDiMode` is set.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, unfortunetly `BiDiMode` feature only take care of texts direction, and the actual lauout remains unchanged (I think they don't assign the job to a RTL person). Trust me it got changed a lot when using this way(SetControlLayout).

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is when `RTL` is false, you are setting `GWL_EXSTYLE` to 0, wiping out ALL extended window styles, including `LVS_EX_INFOTIP`. You need to preserve the styles you are not interested in changing, eg:

```pascal
procedure SetControlLayout(Control: TWinControl; RTL: Boolean);
const
  LVM_FIRST = $1000;
  LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31; // ListView header messages
  HeaderRTLStyles = WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
    //or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT
    ;
  ControlRTLStyles = WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
    or WS_EX_RTLREADING
    or WS_EX_LEFT
    //or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT
    ;
var
  Header: HWND;
  ExStyles: LONG_PTR;
begin
  if Control is TListView then
  begin
    Header := SendMessage(Control.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
    if Header <> 0 then
    begin
      ExStyles := GetWindowLongPtr(Header, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      if RTL then
        ExStyles := ExStyles or HeaderRTLStyles
      else
        ExStyles := ExStyles and not HeaderRTLStyles;

      SetWindowLongPtr(Header, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyles);
    end;
  end;

  ExStyles := GetWindowLongPtr(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if RTL then
    ExStyles := ExStyles or ControlRTLStyles
  else
    ExStyles := ExStyles and not ControlRTLStyles;

  SetWindowLongPtr(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyles);

  Control.Invalidate;
end;
```

Another problem I see is that `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` has the same numeric value as `LVS_EX_TRANSPARENTBKGND`. ListView extended window styles can't be set with `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_EXSTYLE)`, they have to be set with the `LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE` window message instead. So you may have to re-enable the `LVS_EX_INFOTIP` style after setting `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`:

```pascal
procedure SetControlLayout(Control: TWinControl; RTL: Boolean);
const
  LVM_FIRST = $1000;
  LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31; // ListView header messages
  HeaderRTLStyles = WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
    //or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT
    ;
  ControlRTLStyles = WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
    or WS_EX_RTLREADING
    or WS_EX_LEFT
    //or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT
    ;
var
  IsListView: boolean;
  Header: HWND;
  ExStyles: LONG_PTR;
begin
  IsListView := Control is TListView;
  if IsListView then
  begin
    Header := SendMessage(Control.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
    if Header <> 0 then
    begin
      ExStyles := GetWindowLongPtr(Header, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      if RTL then
        ExStyles := ExStyles or HeaderRTLStyles
      else
        ExStyles := ExStyles and not HeaderRTLStyles;

      SetWindowLongPtr(Header, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyles);
    end;
  end;

  ExStyles := GetWindowLongPtr(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if RTL then
    ExStyles := ExStyles or ControlRTLStyles
  else
    ExStyles := ExStyles and not ControlRTLStyles;

  SetWindowLongPtr(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyles);

  if IsListView then
    Control.Perform(LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, LVS_EX_INFOTIP, LVS_EX_INFOTIP);

  Control.Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: I have just commented `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` to remove RTL layout(no false value for RTL). After that tooltip is shown. The problem is RTL is true but tooltip isn't shown.